# Ror twitter gem user_timeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I'm new to RoR and I have troubles when trying to pull tweets using [sferik gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter).

I've edited my gemfile:

> gem 'twitter'

and run `bundle install`.

I have `twitter.rb` in `config/initializers/` folder (in app I have real keys):

```
$client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key = 'consumer_key'
  config.consumer_secret = 'consumer_secret'
  config.access_token = 'access_token'
  config.access_token_secret = 'access_token_secret'
end
```

I'm trying to do the following in my controller:

```
def index
    load_tweets
end

def load_tweets
    #@tweets = $client.user_timeline('test')
    $client.update("I'm tweeting with @gem!")
end
```

But both lines give me error:
Twitter::Error in IndexController#index

Full stack:

```
twitter (5.4.1) lib/twitter/rest/client.rb:143:in `rescue in request'
twitter (5.4.1) lib/twitter/rest/client.rb:131:in `request'
twitter (5.4.1) lib/twitter/rest/client.rb:97:in `get'
twitter (5.4.1) lib/twitter/rest/api/utils.rb:86:in `objects_from_response'
twitter (5.4.1) lib/twitter/rest/api/utils.rb:77:in `objects_from_response_with_user'
twitter (5.4.1) lib/twitter/rest/api/timelines.rb:50:in `user_timeline'
app/controllers/index_controller.rb:51:in `load_tweets'
app/controllers/index_controller.rb:8:in `index'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__531174463__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1028655898__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread
```

Are there any problem with my code?

Comment: Please add the full stack trace from your log.

Comment: Also make sure your Twitter application has permission to read/write. I think the default is read only.

Answer (score 1):

twitter.rb is already existing in twitter gem. Try changing your config/initializers/twitter.rb to something else.